# How does google docs do real time syncing? Websocket?

Tags: web, websocket, google-docs

Applications such as google docs and notion can sync in realtime.
How is this achieved? I know websocket can do something like this.

But I didn't see any websocket traffic in the developer tool. Instead I saw get and post requests. How can this be achieved with GET/POST request?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What technology does Google Drive use to get real-time updates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35070217/what-technology-does-google-drive-use-to-get-real-time-updates)