# Realtime communication between NodeJS server and browser

Tags: javascript, websocket

I am currently working in a feature that requires real time communication between browser and server and I am using websocket for the same. But I was a bit surprised when I looked at [Google Keep webapp](https://keep.google.com). When I open the network panel I don't see any Websocket or SSE connection being established but if I keep the web app open and make any change on the android app and pull down on the screen on the android app to sync changes, the web app gets refreshed immediately.

Since there is no active Websocket or SSE connection seen in the network panel I am curious if there is any other mechanism to achieve the same without using Websockets?

Comment: Google Keep appears to just poll over HTTP.

Comment: What we did before WebSockets.... polling with http connections.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35070217/what-technology-does-google-drive-use-to-get-real-time-updates) could explain how google keep works, even if in that answer they talk about google drive.